# I cannot point out the error on Ajax Jquery, data doesnt seem to get by $_REQUEST in login.php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, web

I'm having trouble finding out whats wrong in my code, theres no error in the browser by the way. The problem is when the ajax passes the data to the login.php, the login php doesnt recognize the data (username and password)or the ajax was not sending the data properly, the **$_Session['username']** is undefined;

heres my code,

```
$(function(){
    var user = $('#username').val();
    var pass = $('#password').val();
    $('#login').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "../ajax/login.php",
            data: 'username='+user+'&password='+pass
        }).success(function(data){
            if(data == "Success"){
                $('#error').html("Hello!");
            }else{
                alert(data);
                $('#error').html("Hello!");
            }
        }).error(function(){
            alert("An error occured.");
        });
    });
});
```

the login.php code

```
 <?php
include '../library/Session.php';
include '../library/connection/Connection.php';
include '../library/Data_Cleansing.php';
$session->LoginCheckSession();
$username = $_REQUEST['username'];
$password = $_REQUEST['password'];
$username = $CleanData->stripAndSlash($username);
$password = $CleanData->stripAndSlash($password);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'") or die(mysql_error());
if ($sql && mysql_num_rows($sql) == 1) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        if ($username == $row['username'] && $password == $row['password']) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            echo "Success";
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Failed";
}
?>
```

Can anyone give me an advise on how to fix this? when I tried to alert the data all I got is "Failed". **alert(data);**

Comment: First of all use POST for ajax, and use $_POST['username'] instead of $_REQUEST. now look at the ajax request using firebug or chrom developer tools and check if the request is sent properly

Comment: Is it possible that there are more than one users in the database with the same username/password? This can be an error that happens during testing where the same user gets inserted multiple times - it would cause your `mysql_num_rows($sql) == 1` to fail.

Comment: @ftom2 I tried both POST and GET method and nothing works, and based on what I read that $_REQUEST accepts both POST and GET so i'm pretty sure im correct there.

Comment: @newfurniturey i'm still testing it, in fact i only have 1 user in my database to check it ajax is working. im really troubled and frustrated by this,

Comment: The password you're testing against, is it supposed to be encrypted? It's only being passed through `$CleanData->stripAndSlash()`, so it's not being encrypted for the database-check. To test, try going directly to the login.php page with the parameters in the query-string, such as login.php?username=test&password=test. You're using `$_REQUEST`, so it should work - this way you can test things more easily and see better output (instead of through ajax).

Comment: no its not encrypted,this $CleanData->stripAndSlash() just cleansing the data sql injections and stripslash. you right i think i need to do this in the simple way and to see if it really works(without the database) i'll get back to you after i solve this. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if (mysql_num_rows($sql) == 1) {
```

Provided that your usernames are unique.
However it is strongly discouraged to keep on using `mysql_` functions. Use  MySQLi or PDO_MySQL as it is recommended on [PHP.NET](http://php.net/)

Comment: ya about this bit of code, it doesnt work, it still displays "FAILED" instead of success

Comment: you have ($sql && mysql... I have removed the $sql && did you try that? if it still fails there are no rows returned from mysql or more than 1 row is returned

Comment: I tried everything in the login.php page and nothing works i even tried to pass the data as it is(no database) like **if($username == "test" && password == "test"){}** nothing happends still displays **"FAILED"** im suspecting that i did something wrong in the jquery part.

Answer (score 0):

use $_GET instead of $_REQUEST and check

Comment: I tried it nothing works, if you could only see in the login.js part i think there something wrong with what i did. fresh set of eyes needed. thanks

Comment: have you traced ajax requests with fire bug ? your method is GET so parameters must be in requested url through ajax. if not so there may be trouble in seting data property in $.ajax

Answer (score 0):

Good news!

I finally solved the problem. The problem lies in the login.js

```
$(function(){
var user = $('#username').val();
var pass = $('#password').val();
$('#login').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "../ajax/login.php",
        data: 'username='+user+'&password='+pass
    }).success(function(data){
        if(data == "Success"){
            $('#error').html("Hello!");
        }else{
            alert(data);
            $('#error').html("Hello!");
        }
    }).error(function(){
        alert("An error occured.");
    });
});
```

});

see the `var user = $('#username').val();
var pass = $('#password').val();`

```
 $('#login').click(function(){
    var user = $('#username').val();
    var pass = $('#password').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
```

They are suppose to be inside the click(function) so that they will have values once the button is clicked. So stupid of me. I'm sorry for wasting you time hope you will help me in the future thanks.